# How to stop a activity? but not to finish() it

Tags: android, android-activity

for some special needs of my software development work i need to have a activity paused (not visible), but not finaliced.

I read this on the android developers guide:

**Activity Lifecycle**
 **If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped. It still retains all state and member information, however, it is no longer visible to the user so its window is hidden and it will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.**

I need that, to have a activity stopped, but not finalized. If i use finish(), the activity can't be referenced, and i need to reference it on my other activities for some special hard needs.

I dont need finish(), because this:

> Finish(): Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The
>   ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go to Home activity to complete your activity like this:

```
       //do something to finish activity before this
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Anywhere when you want to finish your app, such as exit button click.

Comment: finish my app? what? i dont want to finish my app -_-

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want? When do you want your activity pause? When user press HOME key?

Comment: no, i need to pause it programatically when i want, when app starts i need to have one activitiy paused but not finished. I need to access that activity instance by static way

Comment: I don't know why you want to 'pause' this, but if you want activity no longer is visible to the user, you should transfer it to another activity. And when you want to resume it, just transfer back to it (you can put some data between 2 activities).